# Could someone explain me what this ".....: " means among the parameters inside a python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I know that python there is a singleton called 'Ellipsis', but it seems to me there is completely different meaning among parameters inside a function. I look up in many other sources and book on the internet, but I can't find the answer.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjqOn.png)

For example, if I write a function, it will compile and no spaces is required as well. Why ?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape((2, 4)),
...                      index=['three', 'one'],
...                      columns=['d', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
```

If I put a space before ellipsis (...), it will not compiles.

but this works fine ! Why ????

```py
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape((2, 4)),
   .....:                      index=['three', 'one'],
   .....:                      columns=['d', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
```

[image: Python function]

Comment: That's part of the IPython/Jupyter prompt - it indicates that the code being evaluated continues onto another line. It's not actually part of the Python code.